# Node.js terminal giving Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am creating an app in Node.js when I am running it in the terminal with `nodemon app.js` command I am getting this error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1259:14)
    at listen (net.js:1295:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1391:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (E:\xampp\htdocs\sites\nodeapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\xampp\htdocs\sites\nodeapp\app.js:79:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('./config');
var user = require('./modal/user');
//var alte = require('admin-lte');

// set up view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// set up static files
app.use(express.static('./'));

// configuration
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// routes
// basic route to home/landing
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

// route to create user
app.get('/setup', function(req, res){
  //create user
  var nick = new user({
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    admin: true
  });

  //save user
  nick.save(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('User saved successfully!');
    res.json({success: true});
  });
});

// route to get data from form
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res){
    //find user
    user.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, myuser){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!myuser){
        //if user not found throw error
        res.json({success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
      }else{
        // if user found, check if password matches
        if(myuser.password != req.body.password){
          //if password does not match throw error
          res.json({success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Password mismatch.'});
        }else{
          //if password matches create token
          var token = jwt.sign(myuser, app.get('superSecret'), {expiresIn: 86400});
          //res.render('dashboard');
          res.send('Logged In')
        }
      }
    });
});

// API ROUTES -------------------
// we'll get to these in a second

// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening to port ' + port);
```

When I login then instead of showing message `Logged In` it gives `Internal Server Error` Please help me fix the problem.

Comment: You have another process listening on port 8080

Comment: even if I change my port to something else say 3000 I am getting the same error...

Comment: how are you running nodemon?

Comment: check which process uses this port number:   lsof -i tcp:<port number>

Comment: i intalled it with the command `npm install nodemon` and running with command `nodemon app` or `nodemon app.js`... is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: Then something is listening on 3000, too, as that's also a very common developer port. Change it to something else.

Comment: ok changed it to 9999 again same error... whatever port I am giving the error is same..

Comment: check if you have any stale node processes: `ps aux | grep node`

Comment: where should I run that command? in node terminal or new command prompt?

Comment: I guess you are using Windows so that Linux command won't do you much. Try hardcoding some random port like you did with 9999 and remove `process.env.PORT` so you have something like `var port = 7987;` (line 18 if I'm not mistaken). Maybe you have accidentally set environmental port variable and it picks up that same value every time.

Comment: @djordjea that worked :) switched to port 3000 and its working now..  but when I will deploy it on production mode online should I be working on `process.env.PORT` instead? or this method will do?

Comment: I don't know how's your production environment configured, but if you don't need to set the port dynamically and you are sure which port number is gonna be used - I guess you can do it the hardcoded way.

Comment: I got my problem.. I logged in and it worked fine 1st time for port 3000. Then I logged in again and it showed error. I think I need to create a logout which destroys the previous session and clears the port in use... any idea on it? can you show me a code example as an answer with reference to my code?

Answer (score 0):

port 8080 is the defaul http port for Tomcat Web Server.
Is there a chance that you have Tomcat running as well?
Do you get the same error if you change your port to something other than 8080?

Comment: even if I change my port to something else say 3000 I am getting the same error..